# как в QRegularExpression не учитывать регистр?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt, qt5, qregularexpression

как в QRegularExpression не учитывать регистр?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#PatternOption-enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QRegularExpression re("my.regex", QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption)
```

или

```
QRegularExpression re;
re.setPatternOptions(QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption)
```

Подробности см. в [документации Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#setPatternOptions).